# Print title band every page

Tags: jasper-reports

I know that the title band is only printed on the first page of the report, but the band still has a **"Print When Expression"** property and I've been trying to get it to print on every page. What expression can I use to do that? Or if it is even possible.

Comment: What's wrong with using the page header band?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though `<title>` band has `printWhenExpression` property, it will print only once. If `printWhenExpression` is true, it will print once otherwise not at all.

You could use `<pageHeader>` band if you want some content to be printed on every page. Alternately you can create a group which will be printed on every page and include your content inside it. Something like this (Note that the `evaluationTime` of `PAGE_NUMBER` variable is `Page` by default):

```
<group name="grpDept">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        .
        .
        .
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```